# C# why is hashset slow in my test. Please help me understand

Tags: c#, hashset

Hashset test Elapsed time:5.38

Linq test Elapsed ime:0.64

Foreach loop test Elapsed ime:0.32

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace _08_ArrayCheck 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var a = Enumerable.Range('a','z'-'a'+1).Select(c=>(char)c).ToArray();
            double sTime = 0;
            double fTime = 0;

            sTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Hashset(a,'a');
            fTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Hashset test Elapsed time:"+string.Format("{0:0.##}",(fTime-sTime)));
   
            sTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Linq(a,'a');
            fTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Linq test Elapsed ime:"+string.Format("{0:0.##}",(fTime-sTime)));
 
            sTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Foreachloop(a,'a');
            fTime = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine("Foreach loop test Elapsed ime:"+ string.Format("{0:0.##}",(fTime-sTime)));
            sw.Stop();   
        }  

        public static bool Hashset(char[] a, char x)
        // isn't hashset supposed to be'faster code  performance wise
        {
            HashSet<char> hashSearch = new HashSet<char>(a);
            return hashSearch.Contains(x);
        }

        public static bool Linq(char[] a, char x)//linq solution
        {
            return a.Contains(x);
        }

        public static bool Foreachloop(char[] a, char x)//foreach loop
        {
            foreach(char s in a)
            {
                if(s==x) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

please help me understand I couldn't understand. my coding teacher told us hashset is supposed to be faster perfomance.

but in my test code above proves it doesn't

or is there something with the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Put `HashSet<char> hashSearch = new HashSet<char>(a);` outside of the test. Searching Hash is faster than searching array, but creation of Hash will take extra time.

Comment: Also, when measuring performance of such fast operations, iterate a number of times and calculate an average time, say, repeat the operation 1 million times and measure the time of that million, then divide the time taken. Measuring such short intervals of time has great inacuracy because of timer resolution and interference from system activity.

Comment: yes i got it thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are measuring the time to create an HashSet and to search int it. Try to measure only the lookup time.

Also you are searching for 'a' which is the first element of your range, the linear search will succeed after testing only the first element and will return success.